# elfinder - data is not json

Tags: json, zend-framework2, ckeditor, elfinder

to my application in Zend Framework 2 I added CKEditor and elfinder. when I want to add an image it gives me this error:

```
Invalid backend response. 
Data is not JSON.
```

in the console I have this:

```
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>***/elFinder/php/elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php</b>
on line <b>645</b><br />
{"cwd":{"mime":"directory","ts":1438003401,"read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_Lw","volumeid":"l1_","name":"files","date":"Today 15:23","locked":1,"dirs":1},"options":{"path":"files","url":"\/assets\/dev\/plugins\/elFinder\/php\/..\/files\/","tmbUrl":"\/assets\/dev\/plugins\/elFinder\/php\/..\/files\/.tmb\/","disabled":[],"separator":"\/","copyOverwrite":1,"archivers":{"create":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2"],"extract":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2"]}},"files"[{"mime":"directory","ts":1438003401,"read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_Lw","volumeid":"l1_","name":"files","date":"Today 15:23","locked":1,"dirs":1},{"mime":"directory","ts":1438002867,"read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_dGVtcA","name":"temp","phash":"l1_Lw","date":"Today 15:14"}],"api":"2.0","uplMaxSize":"64M"}
```

**EDIT:**

On the test server integrates all over again: http://kodowanie.esy.es/ckeditor/ and everything works.

When ive loaded files to my application I have a problem.

when I want to add files gives me an error:

```
Invalid backend response.
Data is not JSON.
```

and the url is:

`http://***/assets/plugins/elFinder/elfinder.html?CKEditor=textarea&CKEditorFuncNum=207&langCode=pl`

When I refresh the page everything works and the error does not appear, and the url looks like this:

```
http://***/assets/plugins/elFinder/elfinder.html?CKEditor=textarea&CKEditorFuncNum=207&langCode=pl#elf_l1_Lw
```

In addition, keep me logged with my application.

Comment: `{"cwd"{"mime"` is invalid JSON.

Comment: and what should I do?

Comment: Add a colon after "cwd" in the JSON (the same error occurs later in the json on `"file"`.)

Comment: : is after cwd but I badly copied

Comment: `"files"[{"mime"` is also malformed (should be `"files": [{"mime"`).